# ArrayList <Double> Understanding

Tags: java, arraylist, double

I am doing a project on `ArrayLists` and mathematic methods such as sum, standard deviation and variance etc and I have come across this `ArrayList<Double>`.

```
public static double Sum(ArrayList<Double> list) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        sum = sum + list.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I understand how `ArrayList` works but I am not exactly sure what is going on in this method, can anyone help me understand it a little better?

Comment: What is hard to understand here? You say you understand how ArrayList works, but title of the question says otherwise...

Comment: @radoh well, I'd say that data structures and generics in java are two different things. They might be connected, but you don't need to know about generics to use data structures and vice versa.

Comment: Oh, so it's *Generics* you are having trouble with? I didn't get that from the question, sorry

Comment: yes it is generics - sorry I should of made it clearer

Answer (score 1):

These are called `Generics`. Oracle has a great [tutorial on it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Long story short, if you write `List list = new ArrayList` it would mean anything can be put in that list: toys, food, books. Kinda chaotic, huh? I bet what you'd rather have are boxes that contain only certain types of objects: a box for toys, another one for food and one more for books. That's generally what generics allow you to do. By writing `List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>()`, you're saying that this list can contain only books. If you try to put something else in there, you will get an error.

To sum up, in your case, method `sum` takes `ArrayList<Double>` - a list that can contain only `Double` objects. You can be sure that all of the elements are of that type, so you needn't check.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: `ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();` it creates a list that can only contain `double` values. A `double` is a variable type that can contain whole numbers and decimal numbers. So creating a list like this only allows the program to add numbers to the list: `list.add(4.3);`

When you call this method, you must pass an `ArrayList<Double>` object to it: `Sum(List);` Then it takes the list and adds every element of that list together into a variable called `sum`. After it has done that, it will return that sum. `return sum;`.

Here's how it does that:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            sum = sum + list.get(i);
        }
```

Its basic syntax is `for(initialization; condition; iteration)`. When first called it will execute the **initialization**, then it will continue to repeat as long as the **condition** is true, and every time it repeats it will execute the **iteration**.

This specific one creates a variable called `i` and assigns it the value `0` for its **initialization**. Then for its **condition** it does `i < list.size()`, meaning that it will repeat as long as the integer value contained in `i` is less then the number of elements in the `ArrayList`. Finally, for its **iteration** it does `i++`, which will make the integer contained in `i` one value larger every time the thread loops.

So our `i` will get one value larger every time the loop iterates. Inside the loop we have `sum = sum + list.get(i);`. This takes the `double` (decimal) variable `sum` and adds to its current value whatever value is contained in the `i` (remember `i` has a number value) element of the ArrayList.

Click this link to learn more about `for` loops: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

So if the `ArrayList` contained the values `{2, 4, 1, 5}` and `i` contained the value 1, then calling `sum = sum + list.get(i);` would add the value `4` to the the value contained in `sum`. If `i` equaled `0` and we called `sum = sum + list.get(i)`, than `sum`'s value would be increased by 2, and it goes on like that.

These are called `indexes`. **Indexes** are numbers used to access objects in arrays or array lists. If I had an array that looked like this: `int array[] = {4, 2, 5, 3};` then 4's index would be 0, 2's index would be 1, 5's index would be 2, and 3's index would be 3.

This image can give you a better understanding of indexes: [image]